# Kali Linux: Cursor not showing

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, cursor

I started Kali Linux this morning and everything was like the days before; the cursor was there. Then I turned it off, started again and boom -> No cursor. I'm using Windows 8.1 and Kali Linux is running with VirtualBox.

Comment: Have you checked Settings -> System -> Pointing Device set to ps2 mouse?

Comment: It's been set to "USB Tablet" I can't change it.

Comment: Why can't you? Have you turned off the virtual machine?

Comment: I have no idea. I just can't edit those settings. Where can I see if I've turned off the virtual machine? If you mean the actual Kali Linux program yes I've done that.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Thank you so much you saved my arse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings -> System -> Pointing Device and set to ps2 mouse. Be sure that machine is powered off to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out there is a simple solution. Right-click the VM from the list, click Settings, click System on the left menu, and change Pointing Device to "USB Tablet" instead of "PS/2 Mouse".

For some reason, all my LFS VM's defaulted to "USB Tablet" but CentOS VM's defaulted to "PS/2 Mouse". So my guess is the built-in templates (or whatever they are called) have that wrong. When creating a new VM, if I type in "LFS", I get Type "Linux" and Version "Linux 2.6/3.x (64-bit)" but if I type in "CentOS", I get Type "Linux" and Version "Red Hat (64 bit)". So, in my opinion, the "Red Hat (64 bit)" template should be changed to set Pointing Device to "USB Tablet".

References:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3506
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6642
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09. ... se-capture